# How to remove show passwords option in Thunderbird preference?

Tags: thunderbird

I used to store passwords in thunderbird. But any one can see my password by clicking show passwords in thunderbird preference. Is it possible to remove Show Passwords option from thunderbird preference? Or is there any other way to protect my thunderbird account? I dont want to enter my password everytime, that is why i am searching some other way..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to add a Master Password.  This will require the Master password at startup to download e-mail and to show your passwords.